# Removing or hiding the gatsby starter toolbar

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I using the Gatsby Material Starter kit for a personal project (essentially to learn Ract and Gatsby). https://github.com/Vagr9K/gatsby-material-starter

The design I want is to have a homepage that doesn't render the toolbar in the header (the toolbar that containers the hamburger navlist). The homepage has a big body and footer but no header ie a giant 'hero'.

After a few hours of hacking with layouts and templates there must be an elegant way to achieve this design ? Any direction or working code to share ?

Answer (score 0):

All the pages in Gatsby Material Starter are wrapped with a [`MainLayout` component](https://github.com/Vagr9K/gatsby-material-starter/blob/master/src/layout/index.jsx) to provide consistent styling.

In it's turn, `MainLayout` uses the [`Navigation` component](https://github.com/Vagr9K/gatsby-material-starter/blob/master/src/components/Navigation/index.jsx) to render a [`NavigationDrawer`](https://react-md.mlaursen.com/components/navigation-drawers) while passing the styling information to it.

If you want to change the fixed toolbar, then you'll have to replace it with [`Toolbar`](https://react-md.mlaursen.com/components/toolbars) and [`Drawer`](https://react-md.mlaursen.com/components/drawers) components from `react-md`.

NOTE: I would not recommend learning ReactJS like this, since GatsbyJS adds additional complexity (that's specific to it) and starters (or any other pre-made projects like this) aren't easily customizable unless you have previous experience with React.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Gatsby Material Starter.